# Django: passing min and max attributes to datepicker in ClassBased view

Tags: django-views

I am creating an expense submission system, which is multi user.  For the purpose of this question, there are two models: `Claim` and `Journey`. A user creates a claim and each claim can have multiple journeys.

In the Journey `CreateView`, the following code:

- Autofills the claim dropdown for which a journey is being logged, based on the claim pk, passed in the URL.
- Based on the logged in user, only shows claims for that user (in the dropdown)
- Sets the HTML attribute's of the `<input>`; `type=date` renders the date selector, and `min='2018-09-10'` specifies a disallowed date range:

[image: date with allowable range]

In the following view, I am calculating the min and max dates, which output correctly in the sanity check:

```
class JourneyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Journey
    form_class = JourneyForm

    def get_initial(self):
        try:
            # Calculate date limit for the date picker
            min = Claim.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['claim']).week_commencing
            max = min + timedelta(days=7)

            # Obtain the claim ID from the URL
            claim = self.kwargs['claim']

            # Sanity check
            print (claim, min, max)

            return {'claim': claim, 'min':min, 'max':max}

        except Exception as ex:
            print (ex)
            return {}

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Only show claims owned by the logged in user in the claim dropdown
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['alloweduser'] = self.request.user.id
        return kwargs
```

And the Form:

```
class JourneyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # set html attribs which will apply to the form.
    date = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'date',
                                                        'min':'2018-09-10'
                                                        }))
    class Meta:
        model = Journey
        fields = ['date', 'distance','claim']

    def __init__(self,alloweduser,*args,**kwargs):
        # Make sure only to display the user's own claims.
        super (JourneyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) 
        self.fields['claim'].queryset = Claim.objects.filter(tech_id=alloweduser)
```

In this code `claim` is also returned by `get_initial()` and correctly pre-populates the claim dropdown with the current claim:

```
return {'claim': claim, 'min':min, 'max':max}
```

However, where I am confused is how I access the `min` and `max` variables, returned by `get_initial()` in the **third line** of the form, to replace the manual test string.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this myself.  My solution is:

In the `CreateView`, put the logic in `get_from_kwargs` instead of the `get_initial` overide :

```
d = Claim.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['claim']).week_commencing
kwargs['min'], kwargs['max'] = d, d+timedelta(days=7)
```

The `min` and `max` then become arguments when overiding `__init__` in the `ModelForm`:

```
def __init__(self,alloweduser,min,max,*args,**kwargs):
    # Make sure only to display the user's own claims.
    super (JourneyForm,self ).__init__(*args,**kwargs) 
    self.fields['claim'].queryset = Claim.objects.filter(tech_id=alloweduser)
    self.fields['date'] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type':'date',
                                                    'min':min, 'max':max
                                                    }))
```